# how to record properties of other variables in stata

Tags: for-loop, stata

I have to generate variables `entry_1`, `entry_2` and `entry_3` which will adopt the value `1` if `id_i` for that particular month had `entry=1`.

Example.

```
 id month entry entry_1 entry_2  entry_3 
  1   1     1     1       0        0
  1   2     0     0       0        0
  1   3     0     0       1        1
  1   4     0     0       0        0
  2   1     0     1       0        0
  2   2     0     0       0        0
  2   3     1     0       1        1
  2   4     0     0       0        0
  3   1     0     1       0        0
  3   2     0     0       0        0
  3   3     1     0       1        1
  3   4     0     0       0        0
```

Would anyone be so kind to propose an idea of how to implement a loop in order to do this?
I am thinking of something like this:

```
forvalues i=1(1)3 {
  gen entry`i'=0
  replace entry`i'=1  if on that particular month id=`i' had entry=1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (although your data don't quite look right for the question you're asking):

```
forvalues i = 1/3 {
  gen entry_`i' = id == `i' & entry == 1
}
```

This generates a dummy variable entry_i for each i in the forvalues loop where entry_i = 1 if id is i and entry is 1, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer.
With that code i obtain
entry_1 entry_2 entry_3<br/>
1 0 0<br/>
0 0 0<br/>
0 0 0<br/>
0 0 0<br/>
0 0 0<br/>
0 0 0<br/>
0 1 0<br/>
0 0 0<br/>
0 0 0<br/>
0 0 0<br/>
0 0 1<br/>
0 0 0<br/>
But I still need to obtain more ones for example for id =2 on month 1 for entry_1...although I think I can generate that using
by month: egen sum_entry_1=max(entry_1)
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is, but glad you've figured it out

Comment: forvalues i = 1/3 {
  gen entry_`i' = id == `i' & entry == 1
}
forvalues i = 1/3 {
  by month: egen sum_entry_`i' =max(entry_`i') 
}
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The code can be simplified down to at most one loop.

```
clear 
input  id month entry entry_1 entry_2  entry_3 
  1   1     1     1       0        0
  1   2     0     0       0        0
  1   3     0     0       1        1
  1   4     0     0       0        0
  2   1     0     1       0        0
  2   2     0     0       0        0
  2   3     1     0       1        1
  2   4     0     0       0        0
  3   1     0     1       0        0
  3   2     0     0       0        0
  3   3     1     0       1        1
  3   4     0     0       0        0
end 

forval j = 1/4 { 
     egen entry`j' = total(entry & id == `j'), by(month) 
} 

list id month entry entry? , sepby(id) 

     +--------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   month   entry   entry1   entry2   entry3   entry4 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1       1       1        1        0        0        0 |
  2. |  1       2       0        0        0        0        0 |
  3. |  1       3       0        0        1        1        0 |
  4. |  1       4       0        0        0        0        0 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------|
  5. |  2       1       0        1        0        0        0 |
  6. |  2       2       0        0        0        0        0 |
  7. |  2       3       1        0        1        1        0 |
  8. |  2       4       0        0        0        0        0 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------|
  9. |  3       1       0        1        0        0        0 |
 10. |  3       2       0        0        0        0        0 |
 11. |  3       3       1        0        1        1        0 |
 12. |  3       4       0        0        0        0        0 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------+
```